# Can't create any function in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm learning PL/SQL. When I try to create a function, it doesn't matter regardless of content I get errors. This is the function I wrote as an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sum(num1 NUMBER, num2 NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    res NUMBER :=0;
BEGIN
    res:= num1 + num2;
    RETURN res;
END;
/
```

This is the error message:

```
Functıon F_SUM created.


Error starting at line : 5 in command -
BEGIN
    res:= num1 + num2;
    RETURN res;
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

After running the script, function is created as follows:

```
create or replace FUNCTION f_sum(num1 NUMBER, num2 NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    res NUMBER :=0
```

Then I try to correct function manually. It works fine when I do this but I don't think this way is correct. For your information I tried pressing F5 and ctrl+enter but none of them seems to be working properly.

Comment: Before executing, have you selected entire function?
If not, try it.
It seems like it created the function, and ignored the rest of it- maybe due to your formatting. Anyway, for sure its not PLSQL problem, it must be some enviromental settings of the tool you are using, or simply you did some kind of mistake by selecting only a part of it what you wanted to be created.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Yes I tried selecting entire function but didn't worked either. I think it must be some settings or configurations related problem like you said.

Comment: Maybe just reinstall the tool. If you selected entire block and tried to run it, it should be created. Something is really broken there.

Comment: I reinstalled the SQL Developer and got the same results. After that I tried to change the function's name then it worked just fine. I really don't know the reason behind this but I somehow managed to solve it.

Comment: Was there an unprintable character in the original text you used? I've seen rare cases where copying and pasting can accidentally include unprintable characters that don't display but are submitted to the compiler and cause weird parsing issues. Try pasting the text in a hex editor and look for unexpected characters.

Comment: @JonHeller Yes, I think that's the reason. I was using SQL Developer in Turkish and it had different letters than English. Like uppercase form of 'i' being 'İ'. I think this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Function seems to be OK and it works as expected:

[image]

This error line:

> PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression

suggests you executed only this part of code (SQL*Plus illustration):

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2      res:= num1 + num2;
  3      RETURN res;
  4  END;
  5  /
```

which results in error you got:

```
    res:= num1 + num2;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

Basically, it says that **procedure**'s `return` should be just that: `return;`.

The question is: did you, by any chance, "select" (mark) only that piece of code while executing it? If so, don't select *anything*.

[image]

Comment: I tried selecting all lines and not selecting anything, but none of them worked either.

Comment: If he would only select what You suggest, he wouldnt successfully created a function before an error.